# How can I check if two binary trees contain the same nodes?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying the implement a function which checks whether two binary search trees are equal, order of the nodes not matter. But my implementation does not work.

**I am not allowed to flatten the trees into arrays.**

this is what I have so far:

```
int isIdentical(struct Node* root1, struct Node* root2)
{
    
    if (root1 == NULL && root2 == NULL)
        return 1;
    
    else if (root1 == NULL || root2 == NULL)
        return 0;
    else { 
        if (root1->data == root2->data && isIdentical(root1->left, root2->left)
            && isIdentical(root1->right, root2->right))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

when supplied with trees containing the nodes `tree A = 2 4 5 6` and `Tree B = 2 5 4 6`, the output should be:

`1`, meaning they are equal, but instead I am getting `0`. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

This is how Node is implemeted:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};
```

Comment: Please spend some time in learning how to use your environment's debugging tools. This will be invaluable in solving this and other problems.

Comment: Wouldn't your two supposedly equal trees fail on `root1->data == root2->data` ?

Comment: Here's a thought.  Traverse both trees in alphabetical order, and compare each node with the other.  Then it won't matter what the structure of the tree is.

Comment: I think the best solution is for each tree, get all elements and put them in an array. Then compare the arrays for the 2 trees.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what do you mean by alphabetical order?

Comment: @MTilsted I am not allowed to turn the trees into arrays. see my post.

Comment: You did say this is a binary search tree, right?  That means you can traverse the nodes *in order.*  The order of both trees is 2, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Implement an iterative approach instead of recursive, using two stacks...

Comment: Well the most obvious approach is to traverse each tree in its own coroutine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a recursive function that traverses `treeA` and checks that every item is present in `treeB`. On failure it abandons the search and returns `0` for failure. It can be your function

```
int isIdentical(struct Node* root1, struct Node* root2)
```

If success, call the function again with the arguments for `treeA` and `treeB` reversed. The 'check if present' operation can be iterative and inline, because it does not need to backtrack.

Example untried code, to give the idea.

```
int isAllFound(struct Node* root1, struct Node* root2)
{
    // recursive parse of tree 1
    if (root1 == NULL)
        return 1;
    
    // iterative search of tree 2
    int found = 0;
    struct Node *root = root2;
    while(root != NULL) {
        if(root1->data == root->data) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
        if(root1->data < root->data)
            root = root->left;
        else
            root = root->right;
    }
    if(!found)
        return 0;
    
    // continue recursive parse of tree 1
    if(!isAllFound(root1->left, root2))
        return 0;
    if(!isAllFound(root1->right, root2))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Then call like

```
if(isAllFound(treeA, treeB) && isAllFound(treeB, treeA))
    puts("Success!");
```

If every item of `treeA` can be found in `treeB`, and every item of `treeB` can be found in `treeA` then they contain the same data. Provided the keys are unique.

Comment: could you please provide a psuedocode for this? @Weather Vane

Comment: I've added untested example code. The iterative search of a tree is very much like searching a linked list, but with the additional step of making a decision which path to follow.

Comment: Even with the typo I now corrected...

Comment: Tree A: (1,2,2,3) and Tree B:(1,1,2,3) pass this test, yet differ.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the assumption was keys are unique, apparently so for OP.

Comment: Assuming   keys are unique is _reasonable_, even is not stated.  Yet if keys are unique, then a length compare of the 2 tress would be a more expedient first test than the second `sAllFound()` call.  Yet OP does seem happy with this.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the main problem was how to parse two unbalanced trees at the same time, without arrays (and by implication no stacks). This solution addresses that, and there may be improvements to be found.

Comment: Agreed.  Yet "by implication no stacks" is unclear as this answer using recursion - overwhelmingly employs a stack..  (Hmmm, or maybe this could use tail-end  recursion - hmmm)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica by "no stacks" I was [referring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72840145/how-can-i-check-if-two-binary-trees-contain-the-same-nodes/72840849?noredirect=1#comment128656450_72840145) to an iterative solution that could deal with two unequally distributed trees.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will only compare as equal 2 trees that have exactly the same structure. If the trees are balanced differently, the comparison will return `0` even if the values are identical.

Performing this comparison is non trivial as the trees can have an arbitrary depth if they are not balanced.

You can walk the first tree in depth first order to populate an array and then walk the second tree in depth first order, checking that the values are identical to those in the array.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};

size_t tree_length(const struct Node *root) {
    return root ? 1 + tree_length(root->left) + tree_length(root->right) : 0;
}

void tree_store(int *array, size_t *pos, struct Node *node) {
    if (node) {
        tree_store(array, pos, node->left);
        array[++*pos - 1] = node->data;
        tree_store(array, pos, node->right);
    }
}

int tree_check(int *array, size_t *pos, struct Node *node) {
    if (node) {
        return tree_check(array, pos, node->left)
        &&     array[++*pos - 1] == node->data
        &&     tree_check(array, pos, node->right);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

/* compare trees: return 0 if different, 1 if same values, -1 if allocation error */
int isIdentical(const struct Node *root1, const struct Node *root2) {
    size_t len1 = tree_length(root1);
    size_t len2 = tree_length(root2);
    size_t pos;
    if (len1 != len2)
        return 0;

    if (len1 == 0)
        return 1;

    int *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * len1);
    if (!array)
        return -1;
    pos = 0;
    tree_store(array, &pos, root1);
    pos = 0;
    int res = tree_check(array, &pos, root2);
    free(array);
    return res;
}
```

If you are not allowed to convert the trees to arrays, you could:

- normalize both trees, then use your simple comparator, but this will modify the trees and is difficult.
- implement a stack based iterator and iterate both trees in parallel.

Here is a simple implementation of the latter:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

size_t max_size(size_t a, size_t b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

size_t tree_depth(const struct Node *root) {
    return root ? 1 + max_size(tree_depth(root->left), tree_depth(root->right)) : 0;
}

int tree_next(const struct Node **stack, size_t *ppos, int *value) {
    size_t pos = *ppos;
    if (stack[pos] == NULL) {
        if (pos == 0)
            return 0;  // no more values
        pos--;
    } else {
        while (stack[pos]->left) {
            stack[pos + 1] = stack[pos]->left;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    *value = stack[pos]->data;
    stack[pos] = stack[pos]->right;
    *ppos = pos;
    return 1;
}

/* compare trees: return 0 if different, 1 if same values, -1 if allocation error */
int isIdentical(const struct Node *root1, const struct Node *root2) {
    if (root1 == NULL || root2 == NULL)
        return root1 == root2;
    size_t depth1 = tree_depth(root1);
    size_t depth2 = tree_depth(root2);
    const struct Node *stack1[depth1];
    const struct Node *stack2[depth2];
    size_t pos1 = 0;
    size_t pos2 = 0;
    stack1[pos1++] = root1;
    stack2[pos2++] = root2;
    for (;;) {
        int value1, value2;
        int has1 = tree_next(stack1, &pos1, &value1);
        int has2 = tree_next(stack2, &pos2, &value2);
        if (!has1 && !has2)
            return 1;
        if (!has1 || !has2 || value1 != value2)
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to return true if both trees contain the nodes of the same value, but are balanced differently? i think that might be my issue.

Comment: I am not allowed to turn the trees into arrays

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think they are equal? They are not.

`tree A` is represented as `2 4 5 6` which I guess you obtained by some sort of pre-order or level-order traversal. If your `tree B` (2, 5, 4, 6) is equal then with the same sort of traversal you'd obtain same order. They are not equal if the traversal is the same.

**Order of nodes doesn't matter:**

If the order of the nodes doesn't matter. One thing you could do is do an inorder traversal for both trees and you get a sorted array from both. Then compare both arrays element by element and declare equal or not.

Comment: I am not allowed to turn the trees into arrays

Comment: It does not really flatten the tree as such. Is just create an extra data structure, which is only used by the compare function. Your trees are not modified. So is the restriction that you need to keep the trees, or that you are not allowed to use any extra memory?

Comment: Do the trees contain distinct elements? And are the trees equal in size? You need to clarify these details.

Comment: You do not need to turn the trees into arrays. You can traverse both trees in order and check whether for every step the element for both trees is equal (which they should be if the contained item set is equal and you traverse the elements in the same numerical order).

Comment: @PhilMasteG "You can traverse both trees in order and check whether for every step the element for both trees is equal" The question is how one does it.